# Docker Container DNS resolution

Tags: docker

We have docker network with name `dockerresources`

We created few containers with name `dockerresources_mycontainer_1`, `dockerresources_othercontainer_1`.

We found that `dockerresources_othercontainer_1` can communicate with both hostnames

- dockerresources_mycontainer_1
- mycontainer

Any idea, how it maps `mycontainer`?

Answer (score 2):

The embedded DNS server docker uses is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/